# Services and inheritance on Android

Tags: android, inheritance, service, abstract

I'm developing an API for Android using a service but have some troubles with inheritance.

I want to permit the future user to define the throwNotification() method.

Basically I have 2 classes :

```
public abstract class BluetoothLookUpService extends Service {

    //Lot of code here (onCreate(), onStartCommand()...)

    protected abstract void throwNotification();

}
```

And the possible extended class from the user :

```
public class Test extends BluetoothLookUpService {

    @Override
    protected void throwNotification() {
        //Some code written by the user
    }

}
```

I start my service elsewhere like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, Test.class);
context.startService(i);
```

And obviously it is declared in my Manifest like this :

```
  <service
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:name="BluetoothLookUpService">
  </service>
```

The service is never launched when I use Test but work well when I use BluetoothLookUpService (of course without specify "abstract" on the class and methods).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All services must be represented by  elements in the manifest
>   file. Any that are not declared there will not be seen by the system
>   and will never be run.

You are declaring abstract `BluetoothLookUpService` in manifest and what you need to do is declare `Test`. Using 'BluetoothLookUpService' in manifest is just the same thing as declaring `Service`, you  cannot do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

It works great, I didn't see these lines in the Doc. Find myself a little dumb right now but heh.